# Как сделать что бы в input вводилось только числа в диапазоне?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такие 3 input 
то есть день месяц и год

```
   <input type="text" placeholder="dd" name="day" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" class="day" >
```

нашел вот такой код не позволяет вводить ничего кроме цифр. Но как добавить диапазоны??
то есть нужно сделать что бы не вводились числа больше 30, 12, 2009

Comment: С [<input type="number">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) знакомы?

Comment: это было бы слишком просто

Comment: А ничего, что 31 ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="dd" name="day" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace (/\D/, '')" id="day" >

<script>
var elem = document.getElementById('day');
elem.onkeyup=function(e){
    var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    if(value > 30) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, -1);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Как сделать что бы не вводились числа больше 30?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```html
От 1 до 30
<input type="number" min="1" max="30"/>
```

Допустимые аттрибуты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ps В вашей задаче я б добавил `datepicker` и сделал бы инпаты не ктивными. И после выбора даты в датапикере просто бы присваивал ее инпатам. Потому что писать дату ручками - это как то не хорошо.